# common lisp - ch 02, code error?

Tags: clisp

I've installed clisp on my fedora-13 machine. In the clisp interpreter, i've entered the following:

```
(defun ask-num ()
    (format t "Please enter a number.")
    (let ((val (read)))
        (if (numberp val)
            val
            (ask-num))))
```

Here is the original code from Paul Graham's book:

```
(defun ask-number ()
  (format t "Please enter a number. ")
  (let ((val (read)))
    (if (numberp val)
        val
        (ask-number))))
```

is there something I've missed? this seems more like an idiosyncracy with the interpreter rather than an error in the code. [Here](http://lib.store.yahoo.net/lib/paulgraham/acl2.txt) is the link. You may have to ctrl-F for the code in question.

UPDATE: haha, right...the problem!

```
[9]> (defun ask-num ()
    (format t "Please enter a number.")
    (let ((val (read)))
        (if (numberp val)
            val
            (ask-num))))
ASK-NUM
[10]> ask-num

*** - SYSTEM::READ-EVAL-PRINT: variable ASK-NUM has no value
The following restarts are available:
USE-VALUE      :R1      Input a value to be used instead of ASK-NUM.
STORE-VALUE    :R2      Input a new value for ASK-NUM.
ABORT          :R3      Abort main loop
```

Comment: Is there something you've missed? Yes, it's the actual _problem_ you're having :-) That code works just fine on my Ubuntu clisp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be typing `(ask-num)`, not `ask-num`, in order to have CLISP execute your function.

```
[1]> (defun ask-num ()
    (format t "Please enter a number.")
    (let ((val (read)))
        (if (numberp val)
            val
            (ask-num))))
ASK-NUM
[2]> (ask-num)
Please enter a number.1
1
[3]> ask-num

*** - SYSTEM::READ-EVAL-PRINT: variable ASK-NUM has no value
The following restarts are available:
USE-VALUE      :R1      Input a value to be used instead of ASK-NUM.
STORE-VALUE    :R2      Input a new value for ASK-NUM.
ABORT          :R3      Abort main loop
Break 1 [4]>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't indicate the problem you're having, the best I can do is to try and replicate it.

However, that code works just fine under Ubuntu 10 with CLISP 2.44.1:

```
pax@pax-desktop:~$ clisp

  i i i i i i i       ooooo    o        ooooooo   ooooo   ooooo
  I I I I I I I      8     8   8           8     8     o  8    8
  I  \ `+' /  I      8         8           8     8        8    8
   \  `-+-'  /       8         8           8      ooooo   8oooo
    `-__|__-'        8         8           8           8  8
        |            8     o   8           8     o     8  8
  ------+------       ooooo    8oooooo  ooo8ooo   ooooo   8

Welcome to GNU CLISP 2.44.1 (2008-02-23) <http://clisp.cons.org/>

Copyright (c) Bruno Haible, Michael Stoll 1992, 1993
Copyright (c) Bruno Haible, Marcus Daniels 1994-1997
Copyright (c) Bruno Haible, Pierpaolo Bernardi, Sam Steingold 1998
Copyright (c) Bruno Haible, Sam Steingold 1999-2000
Copyright (c) Sam Steingold, Bruno Haible 2001-2008

Type :h and hit Enter for context help.

[1]> (defun ask-num ()
    (format t "Please enter a number.")
    (let ((val (read)))
        (if (numberp val)
            val
            (ask-num))))
ASK-NUM
[2]> (ask-num)
Please enter a number.hello
Please enter a number.goodbye
Please enter a number.3141592653589
3141592653589
[3]>
```

So, all I can really suggest is that you try to do *exactly* what the above transcript shows. If that still has a problem, make sure you have a recent version of CLISP and update the question with the actual problem you're having (all good questions should have expected *and* actual behaviour along with the circumstances leading up to the problem).

---

Now that you've posted your actual error, we can see it's a simple matter of how you called the function in the first place. You have to call it with `(ask-num)`, as specified in the link you gave:

```
(ask-number)
Please enter a number. a
Please enter a number. (ho hum)
Please enter a number. 52
52
```

The reason why you're getting that error is because an unadorned `ask-num` is being evaluated as a variable (when, in reality, it's a function). You can see this in action here:

```
pax@pax-desktop:~$ clisp
: : : : :
Type :h and hit Enter for context help.

[1]> 42
42
[2]> myvar

*** - EVAL: variable MYVAR has no value
The following restarts are available:
USE-VALUE      :R1      You may input a value to be used instead of MYVAR.
STORE-VALUE    :R2      You may input a new value for MYVAR.
ABORT          :R3      Abort main loop
Break 1 [3]> (set 'myvar 42)
42
Break 1 [3]> myvar
42
Break 1 [3]>
```

Answer (score 0):

As paxdiablo said, clisp was trying to evaluate ask-num as a variable. Common Lisp has separate namespaces for functions and other kinds of values. You might expect a function to just be treated as a a value which happens to be a closure, but instead they're stored and looked up separately.

If you did want the closure, you could enter

```
[1]> #'ASK-NUM
```

which returns

```
#<FUNCTION ASK-NUM NIL (DECLARE (SYSTEM::IN-DEFUN ASK-NUM))
  (BLOCK ASK-NUM (FORMAT T "Please enter a number.")
   (LET ((VAL (READ))) (IF (NUMBERP VAL) VAL (ASK-NUM))))>
```

You can read more about it here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Lisp#The_function_namespace